# Changing Owner/Group ID In PHP

Tags: php, file-ownership

In my client's ftp the old files have `3002 3000` value in owner/group column.

But when I upload a new page it has 3002 3002 and I can't access this file.

When I try to load this new page it displays error:

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

Why this happen?

If there is any php code to change the `3002 3002` to `3002 3000`?

How can I change owner/group value ? Can I change the owner/group Id using any php code?

I already used `chown()` function , but nothing will happen the owner/group column value in ftp still displaying 3002 3002

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

// File name and username to use
$file_name= "test.php";
$path = "/home/sites/public_html/login/" . $file_name ;
$user_name = "root";

// Set the user
chown($path, $user_name);

// Check the result
$stat = stat($path);
print_r(posix_getpwuid($stat['uid']));

?>
```

It will return something like :-

```
Array
(
    [name] => root
    [passwd] => x
    [uid] => 0
    [gid] => 0
    [gecos] => root
    [dir] => /root
    [shell] => /bin/bash
)
```

For Changing a file's group :-

```
  <?php
     $filename = 'file.txt';
     $format = "%s's Group ID @ %s: %d\n";
     printf($format, $filename, date('r'), filegroup($filename));
     chgrp($filename, 8);
     clearstatcache(); // do not cache filegroup() results
     printf($format, $filename, date('r'), filegroup($filename));
  ?>
```

Comment: here what is root?If it is ftp username?

Comment: No , root is username (owner) of the file.

Comment: i cant understand.whoose username is root?I think there is no need to change root.is it?

Comment: what is the name of the current user of the file ?

Comment: if you are getting NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error , then it may be issue in your htaacess file or The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`chown()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) to change the files' owner.

Comment: i already used this function , but nothing will happen the owner/group column value in ftp still displaying 3002 3002

Answer (score 1):

1. chgrp() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php
2. chown() http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php

Answer (score 1):

> When i try to load this new page it displays error:

And why are you trying to change the owner and group of the file? Is it at all possible that the error is actually in something else? Try checking the logs to see what the error "500" means. If you've moved servers, the owner and group may not be the only issue, it may be that some PHP modules haven't been compiled, while you're relying on them.

A permissions issue would actually probably yield a 403 Forbidden, not a 500 Internal Server Error. Again, check your logs to find out what is actually going wrong.